# Kafka streams NoClassDefFoundError ByteBufferInputStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying the following Kafka stream sample code.
http://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation/streams/tutorial

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStreamBuilder;

@WebServlet("/KafkaStreamsTest")
public class KafkaStreamsTest extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     *
     */
    private final String topic = "testtopic";
    private final String streamouttopic = "streamtesttopic";
    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "SampleStreamProducer";
    JSONObject jsonObject;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    }

    // Do the same thing for GET and POST requests
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("Server called");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost");
        props.put("group.id", CLIENT_ID);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, CLIENT_ID);

        props.put(StreamsConfig.KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

        KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
        builder.stream(topic).to(streamouttopic);

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
        streams.start();
        latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);   
    }
}
```

When I run this, I am getting error as

```
Exception in thread "StreamThread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/record/ByteBufferInputStream
```

Could someone guide me what could the reason? I have kafka-clients-0.11.0.0-cp1.jar, kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar and other required JAR files included in this Eclipse project.

Comment: Why do you use `kafka-streams-0.10.0.0.jar` but not `kafka-streams-0.11.0.0-cp1.jar`

Comment: I downloaded kafka-streams-0.11.0.0.jar, looks like it is fine now. I am testing this further. Will update

Comment: Btw: latest AK release is 1.1 -- you might want to use 1.1. for clients and kafka-streams instead of 0.11.0.0 (that also has two bug-fix releases, thus using 0.11.0.2 would be recommended anyway)